# Routing Cakephp with BACKBONE JS

Tags: backbone.js, routes, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-3.0

```
<script>
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
          template: '<h1>Home</h1>',
          initialize: function () {
              this.render();
          },
          render: function () {
              this.$el.html(this.template);
          }
      });
    var AboutView = Backbone.View.extend({
          template: '<h1>About</h1>',
          initialize: function () {
              this.render();
          },
          render: function () {
              this.$el.html(this.template);
          }
      });

      var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
          routes: {          
              '': 'homeRoute',
              'home': 'homeRoute',
              'about': 'aboutRoute',          
          },
          homeRoute: function () {
              var homeView = new HomeView();          
              $(".content").html(homeView.el);
          },
          aboutRoute: function () {
              var aboutView = new AboutView();          
              $(".content").html(aboutView.el);
          }
      });

      var appRouter = new AppRouter();
      Backbone.history.start();
    </script>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('Home',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'home')); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('About',array('controller' =>'pages','action' => 'about')); ?></li>
    </ul> 

    How to convert the code above to make backbone.js like this in manual coding I seen in the NET.
    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#/home">Home</a>
        <a href="#/about">About</a> 
    </div>   
    <div class="content">
    </div>
```

Im just new to this one guys please help me. Im reading Backbone js now, can anybody help me with this problem. If you have experience with cakephp backbone js.. I also wanted using it on CRUD cakephp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a friendly reminder: `CakePHP` is a **server-side** library whose responsibility is to send HTML or some serialized data (JSON, XML, binary, etc.) to your browser.

`backbone.js` is a **client-side** library that provides **building blocks** for client-side content and event-handling. The only relationship between `CakePHP` and `backbone.js` is that `CakePHP` is perhaps responsible for delivering whatever scripts and assets your client needs. There is probably nothing that you can learn about `backbone.js` that is specific to `CakePHP`. So try to think in terms of "client" and "server" rather than `backbone` and `Cake`.

Now, almost every web site will have some links. When a user clicks a link the browser treats it as an event and responds accordingly.

JavaScript clients can extend the browser functionality by getting in between the browser and the event - that is, by telling the browser, "I will handle this event, not you."

In `backbone.js`, the [`Backbone.history.start` method](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-213) is what tells the browser to back off and let `backbone` take care of certain events:

- [`window.onhashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange): This is supported by all browsers and is called whenever the "hash" part of the URL changes; for instance, if you click an anchor link `<a href="#somewhere">Go somewhere</a>` the event will fire and the listener will be called. If the listener returns something other than `true` then the browser will not handle the event as usual, but otherwise, your browser URL will change to `/path/to/page#somewhere`
- [`history.pushState` and `window.onpopstate`](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html): This is a new feature in HTML5 so it is not supported by older browsers, but at this point, it is fairly widely-adopted and available. Basically, this is a powerful API that gives client developers a way to manipulate and rewrite the history of a browser's navigation - not just the `hash` part of the URL, the whole thing - using syntax (see link) like `history.pushState(undefined, undefined, 'not/a/real/path');`. Correspondingly, there is an event handler `window.onpopstate` that will be called whenever the browser moves *forward or backward in the history chain*, but **!NOT!** when we call `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState`. This is a good behavior and by design.

[You need to decide what you want to use - hash-style URLs and/or "real" URLs - and then configure `Backbone.history.start` arguments accordingly](http://backbonejs.org/#History-start). You can use both but I don't recommend it.

#### Finally, please make sure **you are setting everything up in your JavaScript wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`. Right now you are not.

Comment: Thank you for your information Sir, Also i want my website to load fast  "SINGLE PAGE LOAD"   and their are some articles that suggest cakephp + angular and cakephp + backbone js, cakephp + ember, what is the best JAVASCRIPT FRAMEWORK to fit with CAKEPHP ?

Comment: @distromob first of all if my answer answered your question please select and/or upvote :)

Comment: @distromob now as for the best... in my opinion I would go with Angular. Backbone is dying and Ember is dead. I don't mean that nobody is using Backbone/Ember but almost all the community is going with Angular and that means it will be harder for you to find help and support and new libraries with the others. Also, I've used all three, and while I know more about Backbone, I prefer Angular too. Basically , you should go with Angular unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: @distromob One more thing - for the past year or so there has been an explosion in tools and projects on GitHub that are "starter" or "scaffolds" for different combinations of technologies. **you should use these whenever you can** because it can help you so much. https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-cakephp-sample is there for you for instance. If you are thinking "no, I don't want vagrant, looks like too much work," it is so easy and it is such a time saver for you.

Comment: @distromob one more one more thing - If you *must* use PHP - and I don't recommend it but it's not as bad as people say (FB uses a heavily hacked version of it) - maybe check out Yii. Yii in my experience is a very solid framework. Look at http://www.quora.com/Which-is-a-better-framework-Yii-or-Cakephp